# Does my Mem Overflow when I Stop Debuging before delete the point in C++?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

for examples:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int* arr = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        printf("%d\n", i);
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Normally, The *arr will delete after runing. However, I set a breakpoint before the delete sentence and start debuging. First Computer will alloc 100 int spaces for me .Then I stopped Debugging before running delete sentence. The delete sentence seems not run. Will computer still delete the spaces I alloc?

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.

Comment: any one can help?